# Get error "Cross-account pass role is not allowed" when I try to register repository in aws elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudsearch

I have a problem registering repository to aws elastic search.
Here is the link I use to do that:

[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html#es-managedomains-snapshot-registerdirectory][1]

And as is mentioned in the link I copied the following code and ran it:

```
from boto.connection import AWSAuthConnection
```

class ESConnection(AWSAuthConnection):

```
def __init__(self, region, **kwargs):
    super(ESConnection, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self._set_auth_region_name(region)
    self._set_auth_service_name("es")

def _required_auth_capability(self):
    return ['hmac-v4']

if __name__ == "__main__":

client = ESConnection(
        region='us-east-1',
        host='search-weblogs-etrt4mbbu254nsfupy6oiytuz4.us-east-1.es.example.com',
        aws_access_key_id='my-access-key-id',
        aws_secret_access_key='my-access-key', is_secure=False)

print 'Registering Snapshot Repository'
resp = client.make_request(method='POST',
        path='/_snapshot/weblogs-index-backups',
        data='{"type": "s3","settings": { "bucket": "es-index-backups","region": "us-east-1","role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/TheServiceRole"}}')
body = resp.read()
print body
```

I also adapt the security and account id and ... to mine.
When I run it I get the following error:

```
b'{"Message":"Cross-account pass role is not allowed."}'
```

Whatever I am using is in the same account also I added the following inline policy to my user in

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "iam:PassRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/myrole"
}
```

}

Can anyone help what is my issue?